# Cannot get contents in a text file

Tags: php, file-upload

Here I want to upload file, first thing that I have to do is open and read the text file to get the contents. Its purpose to make a validation and filtering the contents whether true or false.

```
<table>
<form id='frmUpload' name='frmUpload' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='uploadFile.php' method='POST'>
     <tr>
        <td><input type='file' name='upload'/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><input type'button' id='uploadFile' name='uploadFile'/></td>
     </tr>
</table>
</form>

$upload=$_POST['upload']; (let say the filename is finance.txt, it could be different name depending on user)
$files = fopen($upload, 'rb');
$lines = 0;
while (!feof($files)) {
 $lines += substr_count(fread($files, 8192), "\n");
}

fclose($files);

$contents=file_get_contents($upload);
$get=explode("\n", $contents);
```

What I got is nothing, like pretending it doesn't have contents inside.
Then I tried to add location of the source file next to the filename,

```
$upload= 'c:/document/finance.txt';
```

Yes, it is working.

It means if I want to get the contents in a text file, I have to put the location of the source file to be retrieved along with the filename. Each user has a computer and different directories to upload some files which of course I do not know the location where the file is located.

What mistakes I have made?

Comment: Read [*POST method uploads* in the PHP manual](http://php.net/features.file-upload.post-method), it explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

See this post: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

When doing uploads per HTTP you need to use special context and `$_FILES`. Is your PHP designed to run on same machine as the file to be "uploaded"? Then you might use a different approach for sure, but take care of possible malicious usage then. And according to your descirption you're likely to run PHP on a server to be publicly used by different users. Then linked information applies and you most probably need to use special input elements, some hidden element and need to read uploaded file's content from `$_FILES`. This is the most common way of doing it.

Comment: I used $_FILES but not working too. The file is from a client computer and the PHP runs on a server.

Comment: Don't miss to provide form with proper encoding and method. Also provide hidden <input> with file size limit. In addition check your php.ini for permitting uploads at all. See the link in comment by Gumbo above for more!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can first temporary upload file (with move_uploaded_file), then read file and if validation and filtering is "false" you can delete it.

Comment: move_uploaded_file() isn't actually uploading files, but moving files from their temporary location to some more persistent one after having ensured source file (on server!) is resulting from a preceding file upload using HTTP POST method to put it there (on server!). See docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php.

Comment: "you can first temporary upload file (with move_uploaded_file)" ... that's what your comment says ... upload file with move_uploaded file ...